# Using a Loop for Input

Tags: java, loops, java-io

Trying to get this to take input of 5 different temperature readings and out put the lowest input. Im new to java

```
System.out.println("Enter 5 temperature readings");
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);



int count = 1;
while (count <= 5){
  int temp = input.nextInt();
  if (temp < temp){
    low = temp;
  }

  count++;

}
System.out.println(------);
```

Comment: What is your question? What's wrong with your code?

Comment: What is your question? What doesn't work? Why? What did you expect it to do instead?

Comment: Where is your question?

Comment: how do i get it to output the lowest input

Comment: i want to input 5 different variables.... so 5 different temperature. for example .50,30,80,50,80. And have the program output "30"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just going to go ahead and assume that is all of your relevant code. If that is so then you have two problems. The first problem is that you never declare low. I would recommend declaring low as an int right before or after you declare count. The Second problem you have is that you are comparing temp with itself. temp will never be less then temp so essentially you are creating a block of code that will never run. What you should have written is temp < low. Here is your code with the necessary changes.

```
System.out.println("Enter 5 temperature readings");
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);



int count = 1;
int low = input.nextInt(); //the lowest value cannot possible be higher than this.
while (count <= 4){ //made the loop shorter because one value was already read.
  int temp = input.nextInt();
  if (temp < low){
    low = temp;
  }

  count++;

}
System.out.println(low);
```

I left the while loop because it is technically correct, but you really should use a for loop here. (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Answer (score 2):

First off, you never instantiated your variable `low`.  Additionally, we will need `low` outside of the loop, so make sure that these variables are instantiated outside of the loop, so we can use them when we output `low`.  So let's do that with

```
int low = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

You may be asking "why Integer.MAX_VALUE?" This is because 1) the variable `low` must be initialized before used in a comparison, and 2) we can't use 0 because if a temperature is not below 0, then 0 will be the low!  Integer.MAX_VALUE is the highest value an `int` can hold, so it's well above a low temperature.

Next, let's look at your conditional, where I already see an issue:

```
if (temp < temp)
```

You're comparing `temp` to `temp`, which is the same thing! This means that this conditional is NEVER true. What you want to use is

```
if (temp < low)
```

So that the low temperature is correctly recorded. Next, once `low` is calculated, you can output `low` by using

```
System.out.println(low);
```

This should give you the low temperature for the five inputted values.

**Refactoring Opportunities**

If you want to make your code cleaner, I recommend using a `for` loop instead of the `while` loop you have used.  This way, your loop will become

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    //your logic here
}
```

Which means no need for the `count` variable.